# I have 100 hundred different items. How to I calculate all possible combinations?

Tags: permutations

ELI5 the formula to figure out all possible combinations without repeating any items but no upper or lower limit of the number to include. Order does not matter.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I am assuming it is a simple formula, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Hint: in any combination, every ball of the 100 is either in that combination or out of it.

Comment: Each item can be in or out, independently.  Hence $2^{100}$.

Comment: Is there a formula for this? What is it called? I need the formula to take a list of these and then spit out the lists of all of the combinations.

Comment: The list of combinations is **far** to long to spit out.  The computation of how many there are is the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick up $k$ items out of $100$ where $k=0,1,2,\ldots ,100$

Hence, all the possibilities are:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k}=2^{100}$$